Stripe Payment Sheet with Afterpay Not Working in Flutter - Error: "None of the requested payment methods (afterpay_clearpay) are supported."
I'm trying to implement Stripe payment integration in my Flutter mobile app with support for Afterpay. The Stripe payment sheet works fine when I use only the card payment method, but it fails when I add Afterpay as a payment method.
(I'm using this package "flutter_stripe: ^11.0.0" : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe)
Here is my implementation:
Stripe Service Code:
`
class StripeService {
    StripeService._();

static final StripeService instance = StripeService._();

// static final String _stripeSecretKey = dotenv.env['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY'] ?? '';
static const String _stripeSecretKey = "secret key goes here";

Future<void> makePayment() async {
  try {
    print('Creating payment intent...');
    String? paymentIntentClientSecret = await _createPaymentIntent(180, "usd");
    print('Payment intent created: $paymentIntentClientSecret');

    if (paymentIntentClientSecret == null) return;

    print('Initializing payment sheet...');
    await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
      paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
        paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntentClientSecret,
        merchantDisplayName: "Bodyshock",
        // Specify payment method types explicitly
        paymentMethodOrder: ['card', 'afterpay_clearpay'],
        allowsDelayedPaymentMethods: true,
      ),
    );
    print('Payment sheet initialized');

    print('Presenting payment sheet...');
    await _processPayment();
    print('Payment sheet presented');
    print('Payment Successful');
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error in makePayment: $e');
  }
}

Future<String?> _createPaymentIntent(int amount, String currency) async {
  try {
    final Map<String, String> data = {
      'amount': _calculateAmount(amount),
      'currency': currency,
      'payment_method_types[]': 'card',
      'payment_method_types[]': 'afterpay_clearpay',
    };

    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents'),
      body: data,
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $_stripeSecretKey',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final responseData = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print(responseData);
      return responseData['client_secret'];
    } else {
      print('Failed to create payment intent: ${response.reasonPhrase}');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
  return null;

}
Future<void> _processPayment() async {
    try {
      await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
}

String _calculateAmount(int amount) {
  final calculatedAmount = amount * 100;
  return calculatedAmount.toString();

}
}`
Issue:
When I include afterpay_clearpay in the payment methods, the Stripe payment sheet loads for a moment and then closes immediately, showing the following error:
I/flutter ( 5034): StripeException(error: LocalizedErrorMessage(code: FailureCode.Failed, localizedMessage: None of the requested payment methods (afterpay_clearpay) are supported., message: None of the requested payment methods (afterpay_clearpay) are supported., stripeErrorCode: null, declineCode: null, type: null))
Observations:
The Stripe form appears and works fine with only the card payment method.
The issue arises only when Afterpay is added as a payment method.
Ensured that Afterpay is enabled and supported in my Stripe account.

Have you reviewed the documentation on Afterpay (https://docs.stripe.com/payments/afterpay-clearpay) to be sure your transactions match the limitations?  Could you provide more details about the payment intents you are creating like currency, amount , etc?
